# Unable to edit vmss instance secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VMSS as a node poll of a service fabric managed cluster. Through the azure portal I added a certificate from a key vault to this node pool. The deployment failed with the message:

> The secret retrieved from (edited) is not a properly encoded Base64
> string

One of the VMSS instances has the changed applied and the certificate is visible in the os profile section, others don't have this change.

[image]

The things I tried to remove this certificate from the instance:

1. Remove the certificate from the service fabric configuration - the certificate disappeared from the list in the service fabric configuration but is still present on the node
2. Remove the certificate using Azure CLI with the command

```
    az vmss update --resource-group myrg --name myvmss --instance-id 0 --remove osProfile.secrets[0].vaultCertificates 2
```

It fails with the message as above.

3. Edit the vmss configuration using https://resources.azure.com/ - it is accepting the modified json and puting it to the server but the change is not applied so it fails.

Is there another way to delete this certificate?

Comment: In above snip are you adding same certificate 3 times for one instances or 3 different certificate added on one instances?

Comment: Two certificates were already there, I added the third one and it caused the problem.